# How to handle modal dialog in selenium webdriver?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog

I have come across the modal dialog on the web page. I have to select yes in the modal dialog but not able to select it. I have tried alert option with it but is not working. The code I have tried is

```
IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.Accept();
```

This code is not working with the modal dialog.

Comment: i believe the accept() is for js alert type popups. I think youll have to wait for element. Or if your dialog comes up in Iframe switch to that frame. The actual source you're working with would be helpful to see.

Answer (score 0):

The code you suggested used to handle alerts:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
```

It won't work with modal window.

You need to handle the modal window differently, as ordinary webElement. For example:

```
remove().click() //operation leading to appearance of modal window
val modalWindow = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".modal")) //modal window, check the DOM for it's correct selector
acceptDeletionModal.YOUR_OPERATION
```